# Saving a database query to a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've set up a simple 'Settings' model so I can create some user-modifiable globals which I can use throughout my app.
This model has `var_name` and `value` columns. The `var_name` is a primary key.

I can access these using `Setting.find('my_variable_name')`, which works, but results in a database query every time.

I'd like to be able to 'cache' the settings once, instead of querying the db every time.
I'm not sure of the correct way to go about this, I'm still new to Rails.

I imagine something like `settings = Setting.all` in my application controller to put all the settings in a variable, then create a way to manipulate a single variable out of it - call it using something like `settings.my_variable_name`...
...But I don't know how :)

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this to your Setting model,

```
class Setting < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.fetch(name)
    fetch_all.detect { |s| s.var_name == name }
  end

  def self.fetch_all
    @fetch_all ||= Setting.all
  end

  def self.reload_all!
    @fetch_all = Setting.all
  end
end
```

Create some settings,

```
Setting.create(var_name: 'domain', value: 'google.com')
Setting.create(var_name: 'subdomain', value: 'www')
```

You can then fetch a setting using `Setting.fetch('domain').value #=> 'google.com'`.

```
Settings.fetch('domain')    #=> Hits the database with Settings.all
Settings.fetch('subdomain') #=> Hits the results in @fetch_all
Settings.fetch('domain')    #=> Hits the results in @fetch_all
```

`@fetch_all ||= all` will call `Setting.all` the first time `Setting.fetch_all` is called and store the results in `@fetch_all`. Subsequent calls will use the results stored in `@fetch_all`.

Comment: Works. Seems elegant to me. Thanks. Although since I have `var_name` as a primary key, I needed to change line 3 of your code from `s.var_name` to `s.id`

Comment: Actually, when you update one of the variables in the DB, the fetch method will return the older value. How can I get the fresh values?

Comment: You could add a new method called `self.refresh` that executes `@fetch_all = Settings.all`.